# How are named queries with parameter markers resolved in the db2 dynamic statement cache?

Tags: java, jpa, db2, eclipselink

I have an annotaded entity which contains a named query. The query contains 3 positional parameter marker.

At runtime the parameters are set and they are binded before the statement is stored in the DB2 cache. The consequence is that the cache is filled with a lot of similar SQL-statements and every statement is binded again and again.
Is there a way to perform namedqueries like prepared statements so that the sql is binded and stored only once, with the question marks, in the DB2-cache?

I'm using WLS 10.2 as application server, eclipselink as persistence provider and DB2 as database.

I've tried to configure eclipselink wit the property

property name="eclipselink.jdbc.bind-parameters" value="false"

But in any case (Default is true) the SQL-statements are stored with the binded literals instead of the ? in the DB2-cache.

Looking forward to any hints or answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use,

property name="eclipselink.jdbc.bind-parameters" value="true"

which is the default, false will prevent statement caching.

You should also enable statement caching.  This needs to be configured in your DataSource if using a DataSource.  If using EclipseLink connection pooling you can use,

property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="true"